# Android: text not being centered inside button/textview with fixed width/height

Tags: android, button, textview, center

I'm having an issue trying to do something really simple: Center text in a button/TextView that have a fixed width and height, my text keeps being pushed down as I increase its size, here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_add_item"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="75sp" />
```

Here's an image of what I'm getting as a result:

[image]

Would anyone give me a hand ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add padding top as 0dp

```
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
```

Comment: Please, try to decrease textSize to 55sp

Comment: Seems perfectly centered, thanks ! I wonder though if there's another way for solving it

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use this way

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="75sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I see, and as you said it isn't that "elegant", the other solution seems more simplistic x)

Comment: But why you don't use icon?

Comment: An icon is an image, loading it would take more time than simple text